# Can the Minimum Distance Function be injective

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, convex-analysis

The minimum distance function is not-injective, where we define the minimum distance function as
$$ P_C(y) = \arg\min_{x \in C}\|x-y\|\;.$$
However consider the following scenario:
Let $X = \{x : f(x) = 1\}$, where $f$ is a ***convex*** function, and thus $X$ is a convex set. Let $x^*$ be a point in $X$ and let us make a quadratic approximation $\mathcal{E}$ about $x^*$.

Then it seems to me that for any point in $X$ close enough to $x^*$ (that is, for all points $x$ in an open set $U \subset X$ containing $x^*$ ), the minimum distance function $P_{\mathcal{E}}(x)$ (as caluculated with repect to the qauadratic approximation $\mathcal{E}$), should be one to one.

My guess is to explicitly calculate the the function $P_{\mathcal{E}}(x)$ and show that at $x^*$ the derivative map is invertible and thus use the invere function theorem. At $x^*$, the $P_{\mathcal{E}}$ function is the identity map and hence its derivative is non-singular. This should prove the statement. However whether the minimum distance function is differentiable is not known to me.

As far as calculating the explicit $P_{\mathcal{E}}(z)$ is also difficult, as all I have is
$$\min \| x-z \|$$
such that $$x^\top A x = 1$$
Lagrange multipliers give me
$$x^* = (I + \lambda A)^{-1} z$$
substituting in the equation of the ellipse to solve $\lambda$ is ridiculously difficult.

Kind of stuck in this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's very hard to figure out what you know here. The tubular neighborhood theorem (see, for example, Guillemin & Pollack's *Differential Topology*) will prove this for you. I would not work with $P_{\mathcal E}$, but rather with the map $F\colon X\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\Bbb R^n$ given by $F(x,t) = x+t\nu (x)$, where $\nu$ is the unit normal. Then $F(x,t)$ will give the closest point to $x$ for all $t$, provided we choose $\epsilon$ not too large.

Comment: Your set $X$ is not convex in general. To obtain a convex set, you have to put inequality in : $X=\{x: f(x) \le 1\}$. Just think $\{x: \ x^2 = 1\}=\{-1,+1\}$.

Comment: What you observed seems to be the following fact: the projection is injective when restricted to a (small) neighborhood of an interior point of $C$. But this is a trivial result, as the projection restricted to that neighborhood is the identity.

Comment: Why is the projection an identity? @daw